# How can I download .zip files from a webpage using python?

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, information-retrieval

This is the webpage I want to download the .zip files from: https://www.google.com/googlebooks/uspto-patents-grants-text.html#2010

Is there any Python code I can write and/or use beautifulSoup to download all the .zip files in, say, year 2006?

Answer (score 1):

Change "yearToGet" to download files from a given year.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import *

yearToGet = '2006'
```

sourcePage = urlopen(Request('https://www.google.com/googlebooks/patents-grants-text.html'))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sourcePage.read())

```
links = soup.find_all('a')

for link in links:
    href = link['href']

    if yearToGet in href and '.zip' in href:

        remoteZip = urlopen(Request(href))
        file_name = href.rpartition('/')[-1]
        local_file = open(file_name, 'wb')
        local_file.write(remoteZip.read())
        local_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urlretrieve` like below

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve ("http://storage.googleapis.com/patents/grant_full_text/2010/ipg100105.zip", "ipg100105.zip")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use wget.

```
>>> import wget
>>> url = 'http://www.example.com/mp3/mysong.mp3'
>>> filename = wget.download(url)
100% [................................................] 3841532 / 3841532
>>> filename
'mysong.mp3'
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem with beautifulSoup might be that the year `h3` is not parent of the zip links.

You could parse the html (use `request.get(URL).text`) and check for the `h3` with the year you want and save everything up to the next `h3` (or end of text).

Then you can `bs4` that or just regex the `<a href="something">`.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code if you want to download the files from a different year. If you want to download the files more elegantly I'm sure you can figure it out, cheers!

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re, webbrowser


html = urlopen("https://www.google.com/googlebooks/uspto-patents-grants-text.html#2010")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), "html.parser")

#linkList = soup.findAll("a")
linkList = [x.text for x in soup.findAll("a", text=re.compile(""))]

list_2006 = []
for item in linkList:
    if 'ipg06' in item:
        item = item.strip('\n')
        #open the url with the item name appended at the end
        #this will consequently download the files for you!
        webbrowser.open("http://storage.googleapis.com/patents/grant_full_text/2006/"+item)
```